# TypeScript having issues locating types with project with multiple node_modules

Tags: typescript

I’m migrating a codebase from Flow to TypeScript. I’m getting `Cannot find module 'SOME DEPENDENCY' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)` for various dependencies which include typings in the dependency itself.

Example of one such dependency:
`./node_modules/axios/index.d.ts`

My project (among many other things) has:

```
./tsconfig.json
./src/SomeFileUsingAxios.tsx
./node_modules
./vendor/node_modules
./vendor/node_modules/axios
```

I’ve tried `"typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./vendor/node_modules/@types"]`
I’ve tried `"rootDirs": ["./", "vendor/"]`
I’ve tried both together ^

Can’t seem to make TypeScript aware of this dependency! Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `"node"` module resolution strategy the compiler looks for modules in `node_modules` for the current folder and then up the tree. In the project structure that you provided, it would look for `axios` in `./src/node_modules` which does not exist, then `./node_modules` which does not have axios, but it would not look in `./vendor/node_modules`.

In order to fix the problem, it could work to install the `axios` module in the main package, or to provide a path mapping for typescript to find the module. Something like this:

```
paths: {
  '*': './vendor/node_modules/*',
}
```

Comment: Perfect!

I had tried

`
paths: {
  '*': './vendor/node_modules/*',
}
`

At some other earlier point to no avail; however, I see how you only need to be explicitly about the extra paths not dealt with by the module resolution behavior.